# how to fix type never problem in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

I am new to react native and was following this tutorial: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSRrxpdMpVc&t=7327s) right now we were making a array of goals which is scrollable I followed exactly what he did on the video, but I am getting the following error:

```
    Argument of type '(currentGoals: never[]) => { key: string; value: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(currentGoals: never[]) => { key: string; value: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type '{ key: string; value: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type '{ key: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

for the function: addGoal() on line 14 with the part setGoalsList. But I do not understand why because the tutor on youtube has the same code as me but does not get the error. Could someone maybe give me a pointer what my error is?

here is my code

```
const [enteredGoal, setGoal] = useState('');
  const [courseGoals, setGoalsList] = useState([]);

  function goalInput(enteredText) {
    setGoal(enteredText)
  };

  function addGOal() {

    setGoalsList(currentGoals => [...currentGoals, {
      key: Math.random().toString(), value: enteredGoal
    }]);

  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.secondContainer}>
        <Input placeholder="regular" style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={goalInput}
          value={enteredGoal}
        >


        </Input>
        <Button onlyIcon icon="plus" iconFamily="antdesign" iconSize={30}
          color="info" iconColor="#fff" style={styles.button}
          onPress={addGOal} />
      </View>


      <FlatList data={courseGoals} renderItem={itemData => (
        <View >
          <Text >
            {itemData.item.value}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )} 
      />

      <View>

      </View>





    </View>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const [courseGoals, setGoalsList] = useState([]);
```

Since there's no type information here, typescript has to try to infer what kind of state you have in mind. Typescript has no idea what you want the contents of the array to be, so it resorts to `never[]`, which is not very useful to you.

Instead, you need to specify what type the state is:

```
interface Goal {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

const [courseGoals, setGoalsList] = useState<Goal[]>([]);
```

Comment: hey thanks it worked another short question. in my goalInput function for enteredText it says this: Parameter 'enteredText' implicitly has an 'any' type. is this a problem?

Comment: Typescript [has a setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) to forbid implicit `any`'s. The benefit of this is that it forces you to add types, and thus it lets typescript provide you the maximum amount of feedback about your code. If you're in the middle of transitioning an old codebase from javascript to typescript you might turn it off just because it's too noisy, but otherwise i'd recommend keeping the setting on. To make the error go away, simply add a type to the variable. For example: `function goalInput(enteredText: string) {`